# Printable protocol for enum doesn't work in unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, enums, protocols

It seems that `println` ignores Printable protocol not only in Playground but in unit tests too. Is it true or I do something wrong?

Here is my code snippet:

```
class ExampleTests: XCTestCase {

    enum Directions: Printable {
        case North

        var description: String {
            get {
                switch self {
                case .North:
                    return "North"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func setUp() {
        let direction = Directions.North
        println(direction)
        super.setUp()
    }
}
```

In console I see `(Enum Value)` instead of `North`.

I could not find the answer in the relevant question into so and tried to google it as well.

**Note.** If I move this code into my ViewController, it'll work fine. Looks weird for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now, not sure what's going on

Comment: It seems it's an xcode bug for me. Swift is developing very fast. Maybe this bug will be fixed in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in Xcode version 6.3. Thank you, Apple :)